# Eclipse RCP toolbar state updates not triggering programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, plugin.xml

**What I am trying to do:** I am trying to programmatically trigger the showing / hiding / enabling / disabling of an icon on the toolbar. This does not work. However I **do** see the show / hide / enable / disable functionality 'kick in' whenever the view focus changes (so I think the XML is valid).

What I am doing: in plugin.xml I have the following (ID / class names changed):

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
    <view id="com.aaa.bbb.ccc.MyView"
            allowMultiple="false"
            name="%view.name.MyView"
            class="com.aaa.bbb.ccc.MyView"
            icon="icons/MyView.png"/>
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">
    <!-- com.aaa.bbb.ccc.MyTester extends PropertyTester -->
    <propertyTester
            class="com.aaa.bbb.ccc.MyTester"
            id="com.aaa.bbb.ccc.MyTester"
            namespace="com.aaa.bbb.ccc.MyTester"
            properties="isValid"
            type="java.lang.Object"/>
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
    <!-- com.aaa.bbb.ccc.MyHandler extends AbstractHandler and overrides isEnabled -->
    <handler
            class="com.aaa.bbb.ccc.MyHandler"
            commandId="com.aaa.bbb.ccc.MyCommand"/>
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
    <command
            id="com.aaa.bbb.ccc.MyCommand"
            name="com.aaa.bbb.ccc.MyCommand"></command>
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
    <menuContribution locationURI="toolbar:com.aaa.bbb.ccc.MyView">
        <command
            commandId="com.aaa.bbb.ccc.MyCommand"
            id="com.aaa.bbb.ccc.MyCommand"
            style="push">
            <visibleWhen>
                <test property="com.aaa.bbb.ccc.MyTester.isValid"/>
            </visibleWhen>
        </command>
    </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

... and in the code where things happen that should result in a toolbar update I have the following:

```
    Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            
            // update the toolbar buttons
            IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
            
            ICommandService commandService = window.getService(ICommandService.class);
            if (commandService != null) {           
                commandService.refreshElements("com.aaa.bbb.ccc.MyCommand", null);
            }
            
            IEvaluationService evaluationService = window.getService(IEvaluationService.class);
            if (evaluationService != null) {
                evaluationService.requestEvaluation("com.aaa.bbb.ccc.MyTester");
            }

        }
        
    });
```

... any ideas where I'm messing things up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
            evaluationService.requestEvaluation("com.aaa.bbb.ccc.MyTester");
```

to

```
            evaluationService.requestEvaluation("com.aaa.bbb.ccc.MyTester.isValid");
```

fixed the issue with the tester evaluation. The command refresh turned out to be a typo :-/